# Last two digits of $2^{11212}(2^{11213}-1)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

> What are the last two digits of the perfect numbers $2^{11212}(2^{11213}-1)$?

I know that if $2^n-1$ is a prime, then $2^{n-1}(2^n-1)$ is a perfect number and that every even perfect number can be written in the form $2^n(2^n-1)$ where $2^n-1$ is prime. I'm not sure how to use this information though.

Answer (score 6):

We want the remainder when the product is divided by $100$. Th remainder on division by $4$ is $0$, so all we need is the remainder on division by $25$.

Note that $\varphi(25)=20$. So by Euler's Theorem, $2^{20}\equiv 1\pmod{25}$. It is easier to note that $2^{10}\equiv -1\pmod{25}$.

It follows that $2^{11212}\equiv -4\pmod{25}$. The same idea shows that $2^{11213}-1\equiv -9\pmod{25}$. Thus our product is congruent to $36$, or equivalently $11$, modulo $25$.

Now solve $x\equiv 0\pmod{4}$, $x\equiv 11\pmod{25}$. The solution is $36$ modulo $100$.

Answer (score 4):

A little playing with a calculator or a spreadsheet shows that the the last two digits of $2^n$ follow a pattern that repeats with a cycle length of $20$.  So, for example, $2^5$ ends in $32$;  $2^{25}$ ends in $32$, and $2^{45}$ ends in $32$ and so on.

We need to find the last two digits of $$2^{11212}(2^{11213}-1)=2^{22425}-2^{11212}$$ $22425 \mod 20$ is $5$;$2^5=32$.

$11212\mod 20$ is $12$;$2^{12}=4096$.

So, we need the last two digits of the number you get by subtracting a big number ending in $96$ from a much bigger number ending in $32$.  The answer is $36$

Comment: A curious factoid:  multiplying any power of 2 (except 0) by 76 leaves the last two digits unchanged...

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**:

Note that $2^n-1$ is prime implies $n$ is prime.  Consider what that means for the form of $n$ as it applies to $2^n-1$.

Find the value of $2^n-1$ for several small values of $n$, enough to determine whether there is a pattern and if so, what it might be.  Apply the same logic to $2^{n-1}$, and then to the multiplication of the two.

Note that for $n\gt 2$ this implies that $n$ is odd.  So consider $2^{2k+1}-1$ and $2^{2k}$ for several small values of $k$ to see if a pattern develops.

Comment: I don't think your hint about the primality of $n$ is relevant.

Comment: Maybe not if you take the Andre Nicolas route and know the formulas off the top of your head that provide the answer directly.  My point is that $n$ must be odd which limits the value of $2^n-1$ and $2^{n-1}$ in specific ways.